# How to create dynamic json using for loop in scala to pass in Gatling post request

Tags: json, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to scala ,Any help would be very much appreciated

I have a scala Map which has around 10 ids and 10 weights
Map(id->id,weight->weight)

For post request in gatling , i would like to pass my request on basis of for loop
Expected json: so for example , if there are 10 key values pair in my map - i would like to add 10 inner array in my final json string and there should be a single request.

myjson=

```
of[
     {
      "id":pis
      "weight":20.3
     }
  ]
```

Expected json=

```
of[
     {
      "id":pis
      "weight":20.3
     },
    {
      "id": 2nd value from for loop
      "weight":2nd value from for loop
     },
    {
      "id": 3rd value from for loop
      "weight":3rd value from for loop
     }

    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Gatling provides [Pebble Templates](https://pebbletemplates.io/) which can define and fill your body structure

There is a example how it works: https://gatling.io/2018/11/gatling-3-pebble-templating/

In your case body will be likes:

```
.body(PebbleStringBody(
      """{
        |  "of": [ {% for value in mapValues %}
        |    {
        |      "id": "{{value.id}}",
        |      "weight": "{{value.weight}}
        |    }{% if loop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
        |    {% endfor %}
        |  ]
        |}
        |""".stripMargin))
```

Feeder:

```
val mapValuesFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("mapValues" -> List(
    Map("id" -> "1", "weight" -> "10"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "weight" -> "20"),
  )))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you please also tell mw how the Map would look like - I am trying to use feeder map , its not working.

Comment: @surbhikhare I added example in my answer.

Comment: Do you know how to populate this map with csv data
Csv

Comment: Sorry it's a different question , but trying my luck :)

Comment: @surbhikhare you're welcome! Alse you can vote and accept my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers