# Convert CSV data to List of maps in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, gatling, scala-gatling

My CSV looks like this

| id | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 |
| 4 | 98 |
| 4 | 66 |
| 6 | 89 |

I would like to produce my output  into list of these maps:

```
Map("id"->1,"weight"->38) 
Map("id->4,weight"->98)
```

I am using gatling pebble template, I tried to read the records from cCSV like this:

```
val records=csv(my.csv).readRecords()
```

and then from these records I am unable to convert it into this desired map.

The pebble template which takes map in this format:

```
Iterator[Map[String],List[Map[String][String]]]
```

I am using `id` and `weight` in my template.

Comment: So what did you try until now?

Comment: Also, you mention Gatling, do you want a way to read a CSV on Gatling or a plain Scala way?

Comment: Along with the above comments, could you also expand on the expected data structure and if it's correct - you are trying to create multiple maps (1 for each row and keys as id and weight. Shouldn't the more logical DS be Map(id->weight) or List(id:{id},weight:{weight})

Comment: @Filip : yes i am using gatling pebble template, i tried to read the records from csv like this: val records=csv(my.csv).readRecords() and then from this records i am unable to convert it into this desired map.

Comment: @JahnaviPaliwal: Actually i am using pebble template which takes map in this format : Iterator[Map[String],List[Map[String][String]]] , i am using id and weight in my template.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your CSV file looks like this and resides in `data.csv`:

```
id,weight
1,38
4,98
4,66
6,89
```

A **minimal** parser could look as follows:

```scala
object Main extends App {
    val separator = ","
    val lines = io.Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines()
    val headers = lines.next().split(separator)

    val result = for {
        line <- lines
        values = line.split(separator)
        mapping = headers.zip(values).toMap
    } yield mapping

    println(result.toList)
}
```

Output:

```
List(Map(id -> 1, weight -> 38), Map(id -> 4, weight -> 98), Map(id -> 4, weight -> 66), Map(id -> 6, weight -> 89))
```

In most cases, using a library is probably a better idea tough.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , this works , however does not fit with pebble template , i was trying to create that specific map. val feeder=iterator[Map[String],List[Map[String][String]]] - Do you have any idea how can i transform the above map to this one.

Comment: @surbhikhare It's hard to help without a reference example, that shows what you're trying to do exactly - you should create another question, that reflects the current problem in the Pebble context (i.e. assuming that this part of the issue is solved; i.e. reading the CSV config). BTW, marking this one as "accepted" is probably a good idea.

Comment: Sure i will accept this , for full reference i am using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182150/how-to-create-dynamic-json-using-for-loop-in-scala-to-pass-in-gatling-post-reque/68190775?noredirect=1#comment120577464_68190775

Comment: i think i missed to explain a imp point : val mapValuesFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("mapValues" -> List(
    Map("id" -> "1", "weight" -> "10"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "weight" -> "20"),
  ))) , i should have asked : how to populate these id's and weights from csv